# Silent rewrite using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to do the following on my website:

Redirect / to /home
Redirect /index.php to /home

The directory home actually doesn't exist, but should be linked to the index.php file. So the server will run index.php, while the client sees server/home as location.
This should be done by a silent request, I believe, but how?

What I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301] # for trailing slash
RewriteRule ^home/$ http://server/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://server/home [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php/$ http://server/home [L,NC]
```

Not working though, it infinitely redirects... how should I do this?

Comment: ¿Why the last rule? If the requested URL (The one shown in the browser's address bar) is `http://server/home`, why redirecting it again to `http://server/home`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301] # for trailing slash

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(/|index\.php/?|home)$ /home/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^home/$ /index.php [NC]
```